# What kind of event would wipe out 90% of the human population?

Tags: post-apocalypse

I've been wanting to develop a sort of post apocalyptic setting where dinosaurs rule the land and humanity is confined to underground bunkers. I've come up with ideas of events where dinosaurs are resurrected, but I don't have a very good idea of what would happen that would cause humanity to become a shell of itself.

Comment: We don't have bunkers for 800 Million people. Might want to scale that up to 99.999%

Comment: You might want to look at a population timeline and see how very recently the Earth's population was only 200,000,000. It was not that long ago. A population of 10% of our current population is not really a "shell of itself'.

Comment: Also, why would dinosaurs in particular come back?  Evolution doesn't tend to run in reverse like that.  We'd be far more likely to end up with some new animal dominating the planet.

Comment: Does the population decrease need to be from apocalyptic causes?  Most (all?) developed nations have birth rates below replacement level already, so long as human life expectancy doesn't increase too much Earth could drop to 10% of its current population "naturally" over a few centuries.

Comment: You might want to investigate the relation between dinosaurs and CO2 and O2 levels.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond 200 million people now is not the same as 200 million people then. Modern infrastructure requires constant maintenance to ensure its safety; wiping out 90% (or more!) of the human population will probably wipe out the required expertise and labour. Also, nature is in a much worse condition now than it was then, making it much more difficult (or impossible) to sustain any given human population without that modern infrastructure.

Comment: Note that anything that kills off that many humans is likely to cause mass extinction of other species (above and beyond the currently ongoing holocene extinction event perpetuated mostly by humans). This goes double if you factor in the climate shift required to make non-avian dinosaurs ecologically viable again.

Comment: There are way, ***way*** too many possibilities here.  You need to narrow this down a lot by specifying what other criteria you have in mind.

Comment: @Brian Drake
 I am not sure I agree. With automation, most jobs today are service-related, only there to service our huge population. Shrink the population, there is no longer a need for 90% of these service jobs. Methinks 200 million skilled people would be more than enough to run the world technology, given that they only have to service 200 million people.

Comment: What's wrong with a good old space rock? It would do the job. Just size it appropriately, and throw in as many co-catastrophes as you need (global forest fires, mega tsunamis, global dimming, etc.) to get that 90%. You can tweak the severity of these by the size of the rock, and where it lands on earth.

Comment: Apropos...  https://youtu.be/UC_gXD5OE88?t=136

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### **All of them, and more**

Nuclear winter (and summer), global warming and sea level rise, deadly pandemics.

And why not a combination of these previous responses, plus eschatological sects promoting mass murders and mass suicides, the collapse of modern national states and the rise of a new caste of superhumans (you can call them moguls, oligarchs, billionaires, rich people, whatever) that control the few remaining resources while continuing a project to cleanse the lower castes?

Yuval Harari mentions this in *Homo Deus*, for example:

> *"The birth rate is falling in technologically advanced countries, such as Japan and South Korea, where prodigious efforts are being made to raise the level of education of fewer and fewer children - from whom more and more are expected. like India, Brazil and Nigeria compete with Japan? These countries look like a very long train. The elites in the first class cars enjoy health care, education and income levels on par with those of the most developed nations in the world However, the hundreds of millions of ordinary citizens who overcrowd third-class carriages still suffer from widespread disease, ignorance and poverty. What would Indian, Brazilian and Nigerian elites prefer to do in the next century? Invest in solving the problems of hundreds of millions of poor or raising the level of a few million rich? Unlike what happened in the 20th century, when the elite participated in the solution of the problems of the poor because they were militarily and economically vital, in the 21st century the most effective (if more brutal) strategy may be to leave useless third-class coaches behind and move forward with only first class. To compete with Japan, Brazil may need a few upgraded superhumans far more than millions of healthy ordinary workers."*

It's a perfect storm, cornering humanity.

A dictator with delusions of grandeur launches a nuclear attack and has his country wrecked by the others. His most passionate followers declare revenge, with terrorist attacks with biological and chemical weapons against these others. The chemical and biological agents get out of control, spread easily and force the population to isolate themselves.

Parallel to this, we have a worsening in the effects of climate change. Events that we call extremes today become the norm and others off the scale are recorded. Mass displacements of climate refugees are seen all over the world, and due to fears of chemical or biological contamination they are not accepted anywhere, many slaughtered up to miles before reaching any fence.

Many of these settlements become victims of their own security forces, others do not adequately protect themselves and are decimated by famine or pestilence. Isolated, they become fertile ground for the formation of sects in which they believe they are the last inhabitants, degenerating to apocalyptic ideas.

Somewhere in the wild on Earth, or perhaps in space (Elysium?), the 1% of humanity (or less) that has energy, good food, proper planning, accumulated knowledge and resources to enjoy good health, has kept quiet, for enough years until the other 99% will either end up on their own, or there will be so few left that wipe out them won't bring any remorse to their sensibilities.

Answer (score 37):

As uninspired as it might seem, what you're looking for might be as simple as...

## Rapid Global Warming

And it's not just because it's a hot button issue. The heyday of the dinosaurs, the Cretaceous, was also one of the hotter periods Earth has seen. They needed this heat to thrive. We're talking 20 degrees above the present day.

[image]

As you might have guessed, high temperatures correlate with high sea levels. Glaciation was reduced, and sea levels were 200m+ above present. This isn't just the coastal cities, this is most currently inhabited land, except for mountains and high-elevation regions.

And it takes a lot of good land to sustain an 8-billion population. If the sea levels rise within a few years, there won't be enough time to redevelop and resettle to new lands, while maintaining extensive mining, farming, and manufacturing necessary for the process.

To show just how big a deal a sea level rise in the hundreds of meters can be, here is a map of North America 90 million years ago. The changes weren't just due to the lowering sea levels, but they played a major part.

A present-day flood map can be [seen online](https://www.floodmap.net/?ll=46.800059,-82.477828&z=3&e=350), though note that erosion and subsidence will also make a difference.

[image]

What could cause such a major and rapid warming?

Current CO2-based AGW *is not that rapid*. Even if the worst predictions come true, it can still provide multiple generations' time to adapt and migrate. That's not likely to give a 90% population loss rate. Also, it's not clear if it can go as far.

A more catastrophic warming event could be caused by a global nuclear war. At first, such a war produces global cooling, a "[nuclear winter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_winter#Nuclear_summer)". Carbon particles will block much of the sunlight for multiple years, enough for most plants to die.

It's not clear what happens next. But one major theory predicts a nuclear summer. As the formerly living matter decays, it bursts atmospheric methane to higher levels than ever. Once the carbon black falls out, Earth will become a massive greenhouse - the perfect conditions for dinosaurs to return.

If you don't want it man-made, a series of massive volcanic eruptions can achieve the same result. But the scale has to be massive, 1000 [Krakatoa eruptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1883_eruption_of_Krakatoa) within a year. Multiple mid-size asteroids could cause that.

The war takes care of how the humans die out. It also justifies the massive effort for bunker construction, if the war was expected or occurred in multiple stages.

A warmer climate creates perfect conditions for the dinosaurs to thrive. Bringing them back... well, that one you have to invent on your own, and it seems like you already have. Given a few million years, reptiles might even evolve on their own.

P.S. You might want to scale that 90% well up, as mentioned in the comments. 10% of the current human population is still a lot. Below is the distribution of all living matter on Earth, measured in tons of carbon:

[image]

Humans, livestock, wild mammals and birds comprise almost all macrofauna on dry land. The rest is marine life or microfauna. Currently, humans outweigh all other mammals and birds about 8:1. It becomes 20:1 if livestock is counted alongside humans.

That's total dominance, to the point that everything but humans is only a small niche, surviving in the few reserves left to them. Furthermore, much of that surviving wildlife is in Amazon, Siberia and Alaska, regions with limited human presence. In mostly-inhabited lands, the ratio is closer to 100:1 in favor of humans.

To make humanity a minority species, you would need a reduction by a factor of about 100. That would leave humans as apex predators, able to partially survive by hunting, if the rest of the biomass compensates, since mass conversion with predation is only about 1:10. This still leaves no room for other predators at the same level. For humans to lose their status as *the* global apex predator, a factor of 1000 would be called for.

8 million humans globally surviving in underground facilities of various quality (some proper bunkers, others might be just settled caves) is on the higher end of plausible. This number could realistically feed from surface sources without becoming so significant as to deplete them.

A 1000-fold reduction would still leave 10k+ sized settlements, which is easily above the thresholds for both genetic diversity and cultural continuity. The society would simplify to medieval levels, but stay robust. If you want it darker, a 10,000-fold reduction would drop most cities to <1k, bringing society to the brink of survival.

Basically, you need to decide where you want humanity to be on this scale:
[image]

I have extended the scale a bit with two unnamed notches.
Currently, humans are a solid "Least Concern", and would stay there even if cut 10-fold. So I placed it an extra notch to the right. Very approximately, every 10x reduction will move humanity one notch to the left.

At some point, genetic diversity would fall below what is believed to be sustainable. As for how to define "Extinct in the Wild" (EW) for humans, I think that point comes when humans can no longer build the kind of bunkers they need to survive, essentially becoming captives of their old civilization. For bunker size, 5,000 is considered a solid threshold from which recovery is feasible.

But that is for a population concentrated in roughly one place, or at least multiple settlements that maintain trade relations. Planet-wide, it would be split into sub-populations. Interconnected communities reaching 8k or larger would have good chance for recovery, and 200 to 5k would paint a bleaker but sustainable picture.

So for a planetary scale, given 100-1000 separate communities, your story seems to be around the level of Endangered (99.99%) if it's a tale of decline, or Vulnerable (99.9%) for a brighter outlook for recovery.

Comment: Just noting, +200 meters nowadays gives you far less than the map you show: https://www.floodmap.net/?ll=46.800059,-82.477828&z=3&e=200

Comment: @DavidMulder Thanks for the info. The map came from a [solid source](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/earth103/node/733) - probably has to do with continental drift and other factors. One could step it up to +400m, though, as in the Ordovician.

Comment: "Humans, livestock, fish, and birds are the only macrofauna on dry land" should wild mammals be added and fish removed from this list?

Comment: @KellyThomas Or maybe it's the fish who should develop lungs and learn to walk! :-) Fixed.

Comment: ZOMVID-21: Yes, that map is correct in that in portrays what North America looked like 90 million years ago.  What is not correct is the statement that the difference was primarily the difference in sea levels.  In fact 90 million years is a long time, *even geologically*, and the intervening geological processes resulted in, for instance, the uplift of the Rockies and the great plains (80 to 50 million years ago).  Today these areas are far too high to be covered, even if all of the ice in the world melted.  OTOH the link provided by @DavidMulder is accurate for sea level rise *today*.

Comment: OTOH, I wish we could change the projection of that map.  Mercator projection always terribly distorts North America.

Comment: @RBarryYoung True, his link is accurate. I added it, adjusted up to 350m to show a more major case. Left the 90 mya old map with seaways marked in for extra visual impact, though.

Comment: For a very concrete climate change scenario that may actually happen in the nearer future and cause such large temperature increases see https://clima.caltech.edu/2019/03/01/faq-possible-climate-transitions-from-breakup-of-stratocumulus-decks-under-greenhouse-warming/.

Comment: Yeah, one would imagine it would take rather a lot these days to submerge all of Colorado. If that happens, you'd better build an ark.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - **Any** projection onto a flat surface distorts North America. That's not an evil one can avoid here. Better to just make note of the projection used and how it distorts things.

Comment: @T.E.D. Yes, I do know how projections work and that all 2D maps of a 3D surface (like our planet) require some kind of projection (I have written programs to do displays of such projections).  My point is that the standard Mercator projection is very bad for looking at North America, and, for instance, the projection used for the 90MYA map above is much better for that.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - It depends on what you're doing with the projection. Its conformal, which means East-west is always a straight line, as is north-south. For some purposes (particularly when showing historical movements of things, or looking at local sub-areas) that's great. If showing accurate total surface area is more important to you than that, yes it sucks.

Comment: @T.E.D.  Yes, I understand that, I've done a lot of programming work with projections.  Mercator projections do not preserve area which is the more relevant metric for the purpose of discussing land area loss to sea-rise,  But worse, Mercator projection excessively distorts higher latitude bodies much more than than lower latitude ones.  For instance, both South America and even Australia look fine in a Mercator projection, North America does not.  Fixing this is not hard, you just change the orientation of the projection.  Point being, Mercator is not good for this purpose.

Comment: The one flaw in your argument is that humans have passed every one of your milestones except the first one, and not only  survived but thrived. We started from only 50,000 or so people. Your analysis would have to cover exactly why only 50,000 people could turn into seven billion people.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond It's only the first threshold - 200-5,000 people - that is the issue! A recovery is definitely possible with a *well-connected* population above 5,000 and unlikely if it falls below 200. The keyword is "connected". If only 8,000 survive, but all are in one well-equipped continuity facility (at least two each exist in the US and Russia), they have a chance to recover if nothing goes wrong. If 80,000 is spread across 1,000 non-trading settlements... Actually it's OK too, 1,000 small chances is still very good. And 50,000 in connected settlements is well enough.

Comment: you couldn't form that sea way today, that part of the continent is now higher than most of the "dry land" shown. their are real projections of possible sea level rise, use one of those.

Comment: This is a slow process that would take many years to melt all the ice...unless some crazy nut sent all the nukes to Antarctica (do we even have enough?).  Humans are great at adapting, even only having 10 years is more than enough for a large portion of humanity to relocate and adapt.

Comment: It's worth noting based on what you pointed out that 10% of the current population is 770 million. That's about the global population in 1770, not the "humanity hiding in the shadow of the dinosaurs" that OP wants.

Comment: @ 
user2352714
 It's also worth noting that around 1770, humans expanded from Europe and into North America. It seems 770 million people was more than adequate for Europeans to colonialize the earth.

Comment: "_it can still provide multiple generations' time to adapt and migrate_" is leaving out tribalism of the top predator. Land wars for arable land and tribal territory (yet to happen) would contribute to the apocalypse.  People across generations have already found it convenient to believe their life style has no connection to global warming and often have no plans to make changes on account of it, at least not before _mañana_ arrives.

Answer (score 16):

## Gamma Ray Burst

Conveniently, 90% of people live in the northern hemisphere, so a catastrophic interstellar event could plausibly devastate half the world by being aimed directly at the earth in line with the axis of rotation, and ‘north’ of the planet. I propose a gamma ray burst, which are conveniently high energy, but can be stopped by our dense terrestrial surface, thus protecting the southern hemisphere.

[image]

Admittedly, a GRB that catastrophically close would also cause a lot of additional issues in terms of depleting our atmosphere, but with some fine tuning, there’s a plausible initial death count so that the knock-on effects of apocalypse take you to 10% survivors.

Comment: Note thought that this just leaves you with half the planet with no humans, and half the planet with business as usual...

Comment: @ZOMVID-21 ‘business as usual’ very much would *not* continue if 90% of the world died. We’re way too interconnected for that.

Comment: True, not quite as usual. But it would be like a heavily embargoed country, such as Iran or North Korea, somewhat worse due to the lack of smuggling, rather than outright medieval. But of course any 90% reduction won't go medieval on its own (it might if aided by social collapse, such as in the zombie genre).

Comment: "Business as usual" for half the planet, "interconnected" or not I don't think you'd get a 90% population loss in the aftermath of what you've outlined, the half left would simply rejig it's supply chains and carry on, I'd be surprising if you lost as much as an additional 20% in the inevitable aftermath, hell! I'd be surprised if it was as much as an additional 10%, within five years the rejig would be done and dusted & the remaining half would begin to expand back into the habitable parts of vanished half, a very significant hiccup but the world as a whole would barely break stride, probably

Comment: @T.E.D. “Conveniently, 90% of people live in the northern hemisphere”.

Comment: @DanielB Really?  Well  that's my concerns not enough people would die countered then  I'd erroneously assumed irradiating half the planets' surface would only kill around half the population  how did I miss that bit?  it's right there at the front, I must be getting senile or something 

Answer (score 8):

## Virus

A very contagious and deadly virus could very easily wipe out most of the human population. Similar things have happened before, after all:

> In the Late Middle Ages Europe experienced the deadliest disease outbreak in history when the Black Death, the infamous pandemic of bubonic plague, hit in 1347, killing one-third of the European human population. -- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubonic_plague#History)

(Bubonic plague was caused by bacteria, not a virus.)

To make the virus most effective:

- make it airborne
- give it a long delay between when it is contracted and when symptoms become visible
- make it almost always kill
- make the human population refuse effective medical intervention (such as vaccines)

Some humans will survive, either because they manage to fight it off, or perhaps they have some kind of helpful genetic mutation that makes them less susceptible. These are your survivors.

This has been done before, in fiction. See [*The Stand*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Stand), as just one well known example.

Comment: So basically just covid with a touch of MERS, eh?

Comment: Historically, however, no virus has done anything even close to that. 90% in a given village, yes. Outside, the outbreak just runs out of "fuel" and flares out.

Comment: @ZOMVID-21  Past performance is no guarantee of future results.

Comment: @ZOMVID-21 the black death killed [between 45% and 60%](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Death#Deaths) of the population of Europe. While 90% is more than that, and bubonic plague is a bacteria rather than a virus, it probably isn't completely impossible for it to happen.

Comment: @DanielB nonsense! They tell me to invest in the stock market because it historically performed well.

Comment: Cases of multiple covid infections have been documented, with worse health consequences for each subsequent event. If instead of SARS2, it was MERS with its 30% mortality, it wouldn't be far-fetched for it to approach 90%... imagine surviving the thing only to get it a second time and croak. Wonder if we'd still have to deal with the anti-maskers.

Comment: Just have a mild virus that causes infertility.  By the time anyone knows there is a connection, it's already spread through the world several times.  The process would take a few generations for everyone to die off though.

Comment: *Just have a mild virus that causes infertility.* This is what happens in the book *Vasreab* (I ROT13-ed the name of the book to not spoil it - see https://rot13.com/)

Comment: @WoJ rot13ing the title is kind of useless for spoilers: people don't know whether they'd be spoiled or not, until they've already decoded the title to find out whether they've read the book or not, at which point it's too late.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I disagree, I know which books I've read where this happens, but I don't know if WoJ is referring to one of them or another I might yet read, and since they rot13ed it I have happily chosen not to check.  Seems quite thoughtful and useful to me.

Comment: So per previous comment, thanks @WoJ

Comment: If HIV had spread through the air instead of the way it does, this would have come to pass already.  We still don't have a vaccine after how many years?

Answer (score 5):

This answer may be too far out there, but please bear with me...

### Women get access to education!

There is a strong inverse correlation between TFR (Total Fertility Rate) and education.  That is, the more years of education a woman has, the fewer children she is likely to have over her lifetime (on average).  This is why most developed nations have birth rates at lower than replacement (about 2.1).  Here is a graph from [Pradhan 2015](https://blogs.worldbank.org/health/female-education-and-childbearing-closer-look-data) which strongly illustrates this correlation in three African nations:

[image]

The high total TFR for Ethiopia, means the population of Ethiopia is growing!  This is nicely illustrated in a [population pyramid](https://www.populationpyramid.net/ethiopia/2020/):

[image]

When women have access to education and birth control, the TFR drops below replacement.  This occurs at about 2.1 TFR.  A good example of this is South Korea, currently with a birth rate of only 0.92.  This population is in decline, as can be seen by its population pyramid:

[image]

If all women had access to education, we could expect a worldwide "Great Decline" in population.  For birth rates lower than 1, human population could reduce by an order of magnitude in just a few generations.

Comment: actually we would expect population to plateau and stabilize, it certainly is not going to result in a 90% reduction in population.

Comment: @John  Some demographers disagree with you.  The U.N. expects South Korea's population to be reduced by almost half by the end of the century.   This study: https://www.thelancet.com/article/S0140-6736(20)30677-2/fulltext expects global TFR to be down to 1.6 by that time.  You only need to halve a population 3 times to get down to 12.5%.

Comment: @John Using South Korea as a model, the second generation is < 50% the size of the first, and the third is < 25% the size of the first, the fourth is < 12%.

Comment: I wouldn't say Education is the issue, I know some very large college educated families.  It's not education that is causing this.

Comment: @rtaft I am the youngest of 10 siblings and our mother has 2 masters degrees, but I think she is an outlier, especially since I was born in the 1970s.  From the modern study referenced in my previous comment: "Our findings suggest that continued trends in female educational attainment and access to contraception will hasten declines in fertility and slow population growth."  Perhaps they are mistaking correlation for causation, but the correlation is clear.

Comment: @John Iran is another example of this trend - average number of children per woman has dropped from 4-6 in the 1980s to around 1.5 today.  There are other factors that also correlate with increased education for women, but currently the trend looks far more like net reduction rather than stabilisation.  Some Russia observers have speculated that Putin invaded Ukraine now because Russia's birth rate is so far below replacement level (plus their anti-immigration stance) that they wouldn't have the population to try an invasion in another decade or so.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 That's pretty silly - invasions are done by soldiers, not the general population, and the invasion force in Ukraine is just 0.15% of the overall population. Soldiers can be recruited with money and patriotic propaganda (18 year olds aren't really adults). If anything, it's because Putin won't live forever, and he doesn't trust his replacement to resolve the issue how he'd like to.

Comment: @ZOMVID-21 it's not the number of soldiers, it's the economy behind them.  Putin's forces apparently ran out of smart munitions (ie the expensive but really effective ones) early in the invasion and many of the failures are due to insufficient money for training, from half the flying hours per year of western pilots to lack of effective formation-level exercises.  Some of the lack is due to graft at all levels but the ageing, shrinking population combined with a petrochem-driven economy would have made things worse as time went on. (Many other non-economy failure points too, but unrelated)

Comment: I am concerned about this answer's attitude towards women.

Comment: @FuzzyChef what does it worry you? I read it as "educated women are more capable of deciding for themselves what to do with their procreation ability". Am I missing something?

Comment: @FuzzyChef  The answer is based on cited demographic statistics.  It includes no attitude towards women.  It makes no value judgements.  My personal attitude towards women (and all people) is that instead of being controlled, they should have autonomy, which includes access to education and birth control.  And it is just fine if the result is population decline or eventual human extinction.  I don't know how one could guess my attitude by the above answer, though.

Answer (score 4):

ZOMVID-21 has already taken care of global warming as main driver in his awesome answer. If that theme is a little too political for you, there are plenty of similar very realistic scenarios which are both inexorable but flexible enough to give you all the time in the world to spin your story in an enjoyable manner.

### Tipping of the oceans

As of right now, we are not exactly affectionate in our behaviour towards the oceans. A lot of junk is going in there, be it macroplastics, microplastics, raw oil catastrophes, lots and lots of containers going overboard and so on.

At some point we can envision a tipping point where ever larger [Dead Zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_zone_(ecology)) develop, i.e. areas low in oxygen. Eventually all oceans will be a global dead zone, and basically turn into a giant swamp of whatever you want to allow in there. To quote that link, "once [oxygen] declines below 0.5 ml O2/liter in a body of water, mass mortality occurs." After this, in your world, the oceans will be a brown ugly mass of deadliness.

If you really want to put the lid on the kettle, invent some process that turns the acidity up a lot, so even touching the water will significantly harm or kill you, and all infrastructure near the coasts will be wiped out as well.

Since oceans produce a [significant amount of worldwide oxygen](https://oceanservice.noaa.gov/facts/ocean-oxygen.html), this will soon lead to reduced oxygen contents, with a nicely dystopian story-line, where artificial oxygen production becomes a thing; where people have to start housekeeping how much strenuous effort they apply to their work, and so on. You can also have scientists measure a noticeable, unstopping decline, with a natural end-of-life (literally), and unfolding political and socio-ecological dramas, large and small, seeing how suffocating is a particularly unpleasant death.

### Storms

Independently, or together with that, you can imagine that shifts in the atmosphere lead to the development of global storms on an unprecedented level. Eventually, monster storms will form that dwarf any hurricane we know so far by magnitudes, which flatten whole continents - repeatedly. Eventually, the whole world will be a constant zone of high windspeeds that twirl ever around, similar to some of the other planets we know.

Humanity's only choice may be to go sub-terranean, with all the problems ensuing, from how to get light down there for synthesis, over how to dig big cave systems in the first place. This alone will take care of wiping out most of us - it just is not possible to dig fast enough and build up all the infrastructure and food processing in time to save any amount of people.

An alternative solution would be to invent some kind of force field technology which allows cities to be placed inside big bubbles or domes that withstand the pressure. Then you can have eco-terrorists threatening to damage those domes, fascist city-states controlling all entry and exit, and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 2):

### **Transmissible cancer.**

Cancer is normally not transmissible between members of the same species, however if the population is inbred enough cancer can be transferred between individuals and the body will not recognize the foreign cells as invasive. This is currently what's killing the Tasmanian devil population in Tasmania.

[The thing is](https://www.ashg.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/genetic-variation-essay.pdf), [by most species' standards](https://www.science.org/content/article/how-we-lost-our-diversity) [humans are pretty inbred](https://bigthink.com/life/humans-are-less-genetically-diverse-than-wheat-what-does-that-mean-for-our-species/). Enough so that we're in the same boat as Tasmanian devils, cheetahs, and walruses, though not enough for 100% successful organ grafts. Which means that in theory, a highly transmissible cancer could arise that spreads through the population like wildfire. Tasmanian devils share theirs through fighting, but other transmissible cancers are known to act as STDs, and there are even some (not fully tested) hypotheses that [cervical](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/2550096/) and [prostate](https://www.bbc.com/news/health-27466853#:%7E:text=Prostate%20cancer%20may%20be%20a,prostate%20cancer%20to%20this%20list.) cancer may be sexually transmittable.

However, transmissible cancerns are super rare in humans. They're basically what happens when a cancer cell is so malignant it can spread to other host bodies.

This would play out a lot like the AIDS epidemic but a lot nastier, as it would take years before symptoms showed up and no one would be able to reconstruct who had been affected. Imagine a disease that was guaranteed to kill you eight years after you had been infected, but could only be *detected* after six when the tumor got large enough. And the problem is very little of our existing medication would be of use, because it's designed to either kill bacteria or act as an anti-viral, cancer treatment is comparatively crude because we have a hard time targeting the tumor and not the rest of the body.

### **Gametocidal pollution**

This is one people are actually worried about as the large number of artificial chemicals, synthetic hormones, etc. that people dump in the water . Specifically the body only absorbs a certain percent of most medications and chemicals, the rest get filtered out through the kidneys and go into the water supply. Some of these chemicals include [antidepressants](https://www.sciencealert.com/marine-ecosystem-impact-psychotropic-antidepressant-medication-solutions), [morning-after pills](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/speaking-of-science/wp/2015/03/30/fish-dont-want-birth-control-but-scientists-say-they-get-it-from-your-pill/), degregational byproducts of plastics that the body thinks are xenohormones, growth hormones and antibiotics used in crop cultivation, etc. It's to the point where the amount of chemicals is affecting a lot of animals, and there's been a [decline in fertility that may be associated in humans](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32168194/#:%7E:text=Summary%3A%20There%20exist%20substantial%20data,and%20exposure%20to%20environmental%20toxins.). I've also heard suggestions that it may be in part responsible for the rise in mental illness and other behavioral problems in the last ~70 years, given so many of these chemicals are known to have psychological effects when ingested over long periods of time.

Basically the way this works is fertility drops so low no one can have kids, and the people who are born are so physically and mentally unhealthy they can't take care of themselves, let alone raise children. This one would be harder to wipe humans out because if people were able to pinpoint a strong link between certain chemicals and health problems they would just...stop using them. Like this is what happened with DDT and chlorofluorocarbons. Or they would invent chemical scrubbers for plumbing. Like even with the aforementioned chemicals, it's plausible they'll be referred to the same way we talk about DDT in the future. In the (mostly) past tense.

Comment: Viruses that can cause cancer are transmissible. It's not exactly the same thing you are talking about as a direct transmission of cancer, but close. And we have vaccines for some/several/most(?) of these viruses. https://www.cancer.org/cancer/cancer-causes/infectious-agents/infections-that-can-lead-to-cancer/viruses.html

Answer (score 2):

Let's not forget the t-rex in the room: where did those dinos come from?

Well turns out, the new mRNA vaccines have a long term side effect: they eventually rewrite your DNA and turn you into a dinosaur! These about 65%of the population chomp down on the unaffected, resulting in a total loss of 90% before the rest manages to reach their shelters.

Edit: As a bonus, this might explain why the humans are hiding in bunkers instead of exterminating the dinos: from their point of view, the dinos are actually humans - their relatives and friends - suffering from a medical condition, and they are busy developing a cure for it!

Comment: I like this one the best.  Looking forward to devolving into a dino.  RAWR!

Comment: This would also make more sense from a storytelling perspective. You want whatever plot device wipes out the humans to be tied to whatever reason dinosaurs are walking around.

Comment: Or maybe Rick wanted to neutralize a love potion...

Answer (score 1):

first, i think i want to foreguess of how the dinosaurs is still able to roam the earth when human don't, considering that if animal can roam freely on land, any human should be easily though.

twoth, the afore comment was right,i think you should lower that number even more. maybe so that mankind is around a few million scattered around the world.

anyway, there's some way your scenario can work out

1.**a handwavium virus, or a manmade virus break lose**

indeed, there is never been virus that kikk that much people in the world. so you can get a handwavium, or for a better call, that virus was manmade. this allow you to design what the virus look like and it's effect, perhaps it's make human zombie like, or worse, a cannibal, but otherwise a human. but that just an extreme example. as any virus that kill that many and has no cure yet would make any healthy human to get away from the virus as they could, this can be done in one way by, well,underground bunker.

2.**a post nuclear world**

for this, you should make the nuclear apocalyse fatal enough to kill humanity and keep them underground but not fatal enough to kill other animals. one way you could did it is that the animals that were up on the ground were made stronger to radiation by human intervention pre war or any kind of handaavium. thus the dinosaurs can be explained as the work of pre war scientists that were let loose.

3.**the combination of two**

this is, i think can be considered the most "logical" answer among the other answer. after the nuclear war, a manmade virus went rogue and kill of mkst of mankind. this virus is incurable, and as such the healthy dig themselves underground. meanwhile, the dinosaurs and many other animals were left free to roam the earth. the dinosaurs, once again, can be explained as the work of pre war scientists.

Comment: I like this post the most.

Answer (score 1):

A [mantle plume](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantle_plume) erosion causing [traps formation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siberian_Traps#Formation) can eventually get rid of 90% of humanity.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this ALREADY HAPPENED.

Europeans brought many diseases to the natives and, as they probably weren't that protected against them, the population decreased A LOT.

Maybe some contact with aliens/some space exploration attempt might provoke an unprecedented contact with microorganisms that could take advantage of our body and it's lack of defense against them?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_American_disease_and_epidemics

[image: Population collapse in Mexico]

Comment: The problem with alien contact is that alien diseases would be unlikely to infect humans.  In the case of European contact with the Americas, those were several very dangerous diseases that had already evolved to infect humans.

Comment: Hmmm true @Zags, although I guess it would be a "battle" between our defenses and alien microorganisms, but maybe they directly wouldn't have the evolving neeeds to use anything from out body. But if the biology is similar in some way, they might encounter what they want in our body. Do not know, I am definitely not an expert.

Comment: @Zags ... unless the disease was introduced by aliens deliberately?  Because the dinosaurs did evolve civilisation, and spaceflight... and now they are back.  (Probably not what OP intends... but it does also explain the otherwise almost impossible point of dinosaurs going extinct and re-evolving!)

Comment: Aliens could also explain where the dinosaurs came from.  They had to kill off those pesky humans so that they could use their planet as a dinosaur sanctuary.

Answer (score 1):

Industrial nanite swarms have been reprogrammed by a virus to replicate and treat humans like outdated machines (they "deconstruct" them). It began as malware written by some kid having serious mental health issues who wanted to protest against some country invading some other country.
It escalated too quickly for anyone to react in time. Since nanite swarms where in use for manufacturing and building everywhere, only people already inside bunkers or living far away from the cities had any chance to survive. Walls of nanite swarms are roaming the surface like locusts, and they maintain all the machinery. Apart from replacing lost nanites, no new structures get build. No new inventions are researched by the swarms. But all the factories and infrastructure are still in mint conditions hundreds of years later because they are well maintained by the self-replicating nanite swarms.
A perfect world with no humans required!

And yeah, global warming is still a thing because the tipping point was reached a hundred years before the nanitecalypse in 2020...
So the dinosaurs that where cloned from frozen DNS and held on some islands are now roaming and flying around everywhere as the nanite swarms don't care about them while they aren't actually damaging their precious infrastructure The swarms do hurt dinosaurs a lot when they protect their property. But those beasts are huge and can take a beating, so they normally manage to wander off the protected properties before they take lethal damage.

Or just have aliens invade the planet, terraform it to an athmosphere not breathable by humans and then bringing their pets too. Aliens at some time go away for some reason. Planet with unbreathable athmosphere, underground humans and alien-engineered dinosours are still there.

Answer (score 0):

About 10 percent of the world population is of white/caucasian descent. So a disease/virus that is deadly for most people but somehow doesn't affect people of white/caucasian descent so much would suit your needs.

Comment: Oh no. Who are White Supremacists going to hate then? Well, I suppose, one can always discriminate between different shades of White - after all, being [WASP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_Anglo-Saxon_Protestants) used to be a big deal...

Answer (score 0):

The old Internet classic End of Ze World https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nZMwKPmsbWE has a pretty good list:

- The ice caps melting (floods the earth)
- A meteor crashes into us (this is what killed the dinosaurs; it would be poetic if it's what allowed them to return)
- The ozone layer leaving (have some nasty industrial chemical like Freon that destroys this and then any number of bad things happening)
- The sun exploding (a solar flare big enough to causes mass cancer, which could also be the necessary mutation event that causes dinosaurs to come back)
- Nuclear war (around 60% of the world lives in urban areas, and there would be more casualties from fallout and the ensuing climate disaster)

Answer (score -1):

a new violent glaciation era! maybe not 90% of the people would not survive but imagine your nice sunny days are long done , the summer averages -50 degrees celsius and winters -100..
this is sci-fi..